# Setting the run time properties on SpringApplicationBuilder()

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to test my Spring application code by creating a Cucumber integration test. I am using SpringApplicationBuilder to start up my application before the actual logic is triggered and am using the following syntax to do so:-

```
    application = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
        .parent(new Object[]{"classpath:file1.xml", "classpath:file2.xml"})
        .profiles("abc")
        .properties("name:value") [It has 5/6 (name:value) pairs here]*
        .showBanner(false)
        .logStartupInfo(true)
        .headless(true)
        .application()
        .run();
```

My Spring application starts up correctly. However, it does not get the values for the property (name, value) pairs that I am passing to the SpringApplicationBuilder(). I have tried the following to set them :-

- Using name value pairs as above
- Using a HashMap of (name, value) pairs
- Creating a ConfigurableEnvironment, retrieving the MutablePropertySources and setting my properties in it.

None of these options are working, so when the application starts up and the code tries to access certain System Property values, it breaks.

Any ideas how this could be fixed.. All the help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties you configure on `SpringApplicationBuilder` are made available in your application's `Environment`, not as system properties. If your code's expecting system properties then you should set them using `System.setProperty(key, value)` or as `-D` arguments when you launch the JVM

Comment: Or modify the tests to use the Spring environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I do understand what you are saying. However, my application is expecting the Spring specific properties when it starts up using the SpringApplicationBuilder. I am trying to simulate the entire Spring application for my Cucumber integration test,  as if it would startup when it is run outside the test environment. Hence, I might not be able to use the System properties for my test.. Would there be any way to set them as Spring specific application properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating your Spring integration test with [@TestPropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html)

Example:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties={"name1=value1","name2=value2"})
```