# Spring: How to set system properties in integration test when @ComponentScan is used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Summary:** Adding the `@ComponentScan` (or `@SpringBootApplication`) annotation to my application class changes the behaviour of `SpringApplicationBuilder.properties()` and breaks my integration test.

I am using a cut-down version of the Spring Boot sample: 
[spring-boot-sample-websocket-jetty](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-websocket-jetty)
I have removed everything except what is required for the "echo" example (and I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3).

I am left with the following `SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication` code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ComponentScan    // --- If I uncomment this the test breaks ---
@EnableWebSocket

public class SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication
    implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(echoWebSocketHandler(), "/echo").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public EchoService echoService() {
        return new DefaultEchoService("Did you say \"%s\"?");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler echoWebSocketHandler() {
        return new EchoWebSocketHandler(echoService());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the following test class (code straight from the Spring Boot samples):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})
@DirtiesContext
public class SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests.class);

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port = 1234;

    @Test
    public void echoEndpoint() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Running the echoEndpoint test. Port: " + port + ". Path: /echo/websocket");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(
                ClientConfiguration.class, PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class)
                        .properties("websocket.uri:ws://localhost:" + this.port
                                + "/echo/websocket")
                        .run("--spring.main.web_environment=false");
        long count = context.getBean(ClientConfiguration.class).latch.getCount();
        AtomicReference<String> messagePayloadReference = context
                .getBean(ClientConfiguration.class).messagePayload;
        context.close();
        assertThat(count).isEqualTo(0);
        assertThat(messagePayloadReference.get())
                .isEqualTo("Did you say \"Hello world!\"?");
    }

    @Configuration
    static class ClientConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Value("${websocket.uri}")
        private String webSocketUri;

        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        private final AtomicReference<String> messagePayload = new AtomicReference<String>();

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            logger.info("Waiting for response: latch=" + this.latch.getCount());
            if (this.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                logger.info("Got response: " + this.messagePayload.get());
            }
            else {
                logger.info("Response not received: latch=" + this.latch.getCount());
            }
        }

        @Bean
        public WebSocketConnectionManager wsConnectionManager() {

            logger.info("Setting up SimpleClientWebSocketHandler...");
            WebSocketConnectionManager manager = new WebSocketConnectionManager(client(),
                    handler(), this.webSocketUri);
            manager.setAutoStartup(true);

            return manager;
        }

        @Bean
        public StandardWebSocketClient client() {
            return new StandardWebSocketClient();
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleClientWebSocketHandler handler() {
            logger.info("Creating new SimpleClientWebSocketHandler using SimpleGreetingService...");
            return new SimpleClientWebSocketHandler(greetingService(), this.latch,
                    this.messagePayload);
        }

        @Bean
        public GreetingService greetingService() {
            return new SimpleGreetingService();
        }
    }

}
```

Running the Application and the unit test as above all is fine *but* if I uncomment the `@ComponentScan` annotation on the application class the application still runs OK but the test breaks with the error:

`Could not resolve placeholder 'websocket.uri' in string value "${websocket.uri}"`.

I have read at [setting-the-run-time-properties-on-springapplicationbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888257/setting-the-run-time-properties-on-springapplicationbuilder) that:

> The properties you configure on SpringApplicationBuilder are made available in your application's Environment, not as system properties.

And in the `@ComponentScan` javadoc that:

> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.

But I don't understand why the behaviour changes when the `@ComponentScan` annotation is added.

How can I set the *System* Property `websocket.uri` in the test when the application class is annotated with `@ComponentScan` (or `@SpringBootApplication`)?

(I aim to use `@SpringBootApplication`, which incorporates `@ComponentScan`, but I can't until I get this working.)

Comment: Will you past the project structure?

Comment: isnt that "server.port=0" considered env property? Maybe try to pass array there and add your own property?

Comment: #Hareesh: The full project code is available at the link I posted at the top of the question. Is there anything specific you want? POM?...

Comment: @freakman: The `server.port=0` dynamically assigns a free port at run-time. That's why I can't hard-wire the URI in a properties file etc.   
The point is that this test runs fine until I add the `@ComponentScan` annotation to the application class.

Comment: The solution (thanks to @GeminiKeith) is hidden in the comments below but basically I had to move the test class into a different package to the application class (and not a sub-package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to add a system properties.

Solution 1:
Add arguments for `Test` in format of `-Dabc=xyz`, that will add property `abc` to system properties.

Solution 2:
Just like floor 0.

Solution 3:
Just let `spring-boot` load the properties, such as `classpath:bootstrap.yml`, and you can specify whatever properties in there.

The annotation `@ComponentScan` will enable auto scanning based on current package or `ComponentScan#basePackages`. Which means `SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests.ClientConfiguration` will be scanned cause they have same base package `samples.websocket.jetty`.

However, `SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests.ClientConfiguration` should not be parsed by `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` cause we need parse it in `SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests#echoEndpoint` manually. It's should only be parsed by `ApplicationContext` created in `echoEndpoint()`.

What's more, `@SpringBootApplication` equals to use `@Configuration` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` together, so comment out `@ComponentScan` or `@SpringBootApplication` will have same effect.

My suggestion is move class `SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests` into package `samples.websocket.jettytest`(different from `samples.websocket.jetty`) and enable `@ComponentScan` or `@SpringBootApplication` on `SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication` and try again. It should work.

Comment: Thanks but these solutions don't work for me:  

Soln 1: The `websocket.uri` parameter is being passed to the `ClientConfiguration` class via a `SpringApplicationBuilder.run()` method. This allows command line parameters to be passed but `-Dabc=xyz` doesn't work. I suspect this is because the parameters are added to the end of the command line (after a `-jar` perhaps?).  

Soln 2: I don't understand.  

Soln 3: I want the `server.port` value to be assigned dynamically at run-time (hence the `server.port=0` parameter on `@WebIntegrationTest`) so I can't hard-wire the URI in a config file.

Comment: Would you please publish your test project to github or just mail it to me? I'd like to do some research about this and to publish any useful information here if I've got. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right, you cannot add a system property by `-Dxxx=yyy` cause you need add it programmatically. In this way all arguments are accepted only by program not JVM.

Comment: I noticed that there are two differences between the original project and that in this question.

1. The original  project uses annotation `@SpringBootTest` not `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`, and the later had been marked as `@Deprecated`. What's more, `@SpringBooTest` will do some more automatic configuration(see java doc of `@SpringBootTest`).

2. The original `SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication` also extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`. This could also do some automatic configuration. Obviously, two projects may have different `rootAppContext`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  
I've tried to publish my code on GitHub...  
[TheCode](https://github.com/daveyahoo/spring-boot-simple-websocket-jetty.git)

Comment: As far as I can see `@SpringBootTest` is not available in v1.3.3-RELEASE. I had to make those changes when I switched SpringBoot version from the v1.4.0-SNAPSHOT in the original sample.

Comment: The annotation `@ComponentScan` will enable auto scanning based on current package or `ComponentScan#basePackages`. Which means `SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests.ClientConfiguration` will be scanned cause they have same base package `samples.websocket.jetty`. However, `SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests.ClientConfiguration` should not be parsed by `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` cause we need parse it in `SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests#echoEndpoint` manually. It's should only be parsed by `ApplicationContext` created in `echoEndpoint()`.

Comment: What's more, `@SpringBootApplication` equals to use `@Configuration` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` together, so comment out `@ComponentScan` or `@SpringBootApplication` will have same effect.

Comment: My suggestion is move class `SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests` into package `samples.websocket.jettytest` and enable `@ComponentScan` or `@SpringBootApplication` on `SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication` and try again. It should work.

Comment: Wow. From where I'm sitting (in a Spring Boot fog) that is very impressive! It works like a charm. Thanks for the solution and for the explanation. I hope one day I will understand both ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding my thoughts on this (from whatever i could gather from your code):

-Try adding the property websocket.uri in you application properties or if your project contains src/test/resources/test.properties then add it into your test.properties file.@ComponentScan should pick it up.

-Else,you could just say :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("websocket.uri","<your uri>");
        SpringApplication.run(SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but they don't work for me:

The `websocket.uri` value incorporates the `server.port` value which is dynamically assigned at test time by the `server.port=0` parameter on the `@WebIntegrationTest` annotation. This means I can't set it in the application properties file.

If I try your second approach and use `System.setProperty()` within the test method I still get the same "Could not resolve placeholder..." error as before.